# How can i convert to the undirected matrix to an directed matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, random-matrices

[image]

Here A square matrix and first figure(AU) shows undirected connection graph and second one shows directed one.Assume that only i have Au metrix and how can i create Ad metrix from Au matrix in matlab?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the possibility to change the direction of your vectors, take the upper triangular minus the lower triangular:

```
AD=triu(AU)-tril(AU)
```

And if you do not want the `-1` elements, add

```
AD(AD==-1)=0
```

This will direct all your vectors from the smaller to the greater number:
1->2, 2->3, etc ...

Comment: for i=1:N
 
   AD( i, AU(randperm(length(AU))) ) = 1;
end       yes i thought it also but then matrix is not irreducible(strongly connected) as first row (or column)= 0

Comment: @Toto: You've already wasted my time by changing the question once (twice if you count the inclusion of Matlab).  Now you want to waste Jonas' time by changing it again?